# How to specify different colors for column labels in altair

Tags: python, label, altair, vega

Is there a way to specify different colors for column labels with python altair? Take the [grouped bar chart example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart.html) where bars are grouped using the column encode option. I would like to specify different colors for each label (Crookston, Duluth, etc). I have managed to set color for these labels from the `labelColor` parameter
within `alt.Header`, however I only managed to set single colors. The spec I'm trying to define looks something like:

```py
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("case", type="nominal"),
    alt.Y(col, type="quantitative"),
    alt.Color("case:N", scale=alt.Scale(range=colors)),
    alt.Column(
        "polygon",
        header=alt.Header(
            titleOrient='bottom',
            labelOrient='bottom',
            labelColor="black", # I would like this to be a list of colors instead
        ),
    ),
)
```

Thank you

Comment: This should be possible with an expression, but it is not working as indented. I believe this is a bug in Vega-Lite; I filed https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/9283